# Finding all the websites which are on a particular hostname

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, dns

I did find this function on stackoverflow which extract `hostname`, `aliaslist`, and `ipaddrlist`,
but how can I make a function which take a hostname and search all the websites associated with it (hosted by it)?

```
>>> import socket
>>> def get_ips_for_host(host):
        try:
            ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(host)
        except socket.gaierror:
            ips=[]
        return ips

>>> ips = get_ips_for_host('www.slowtravelmagazine.com')
>>> print(repr(ips))
('ext-cust.squarespace.com', ['www.slowtravelmagazine.com'],
 ['198.185.159.144', '198.185.159.145', '198.49.23.144',
  '198.49.23.145'])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all the websites associated with it (hosted by it)"? Often a single hostname, or even a single IP, will have a bunch of identical web servers behind it all hosting the same site. Sometimes, `www.spam.com/eggs` and `www.spam.com/beans` are effectively separate sites (think of github.io, or Geocities). Whether `http://spam.com` and `https://spam.com` are the same site or not depends on what SpamCo wanted to do. Sometimes multiple sites with different domain names share the same IP address as virtual servers. And so on.

Comment: suppose i need all the websites hosted on squarespace.com like [http://www.slowtravelmagazine.com/](http://www.slowtravelmagazine.com/).

Comment: One of the things SquareSpace advertises is that the fact that you're hosted on SquareSpace is invisible to your customers, including via things like `whois` searches. So, unless they're lying in their ads, what you're asking for ought to be impossible.

Comment: Please take a look at the code above in my query it shows the hostname as a first element in a tuple. I'm not sure if they are lying. But in my case i want opposite, i have hostname and i need to find all the websites associated with it.

Comment: This (`gethostbyname_ex`) result does not prove anything, nor what you want to do is possible. The first element is just the reverse name attached to the IP. It could be anything, so you will have false positives and negatives. Also it does not support IPv6 which nowadays is a problem. You would have maybe more helpful replies if you give more context, what are you constraints and for which names you want to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least not with a built in function. You would need a datasource that contains all websites with their associated IP addresses.

There are probably some providers out there that have an API for this.